Integrated Webcam not working Macbook Pro 2015 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I have installed my 2015 Macbook Pro with Voyager Linux 24.04LTS. However, I am unable to get the integrated webcam working. All repos and software are up to date, however I get no picture when using cheese or Gnome Camera. I'm trying to search for a solution, ... Any help would be much appreciated.
